# OS X equivalent to Windows Key + P

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, system-preferences

What is the equivalent in Mac OS X to the Win+P key, which opens the external display options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> (or whatever keys correspond to the brightness media keys)

Comment: You learn something new every day here.

Comment: Thanks!
I'm running OSX Lion, Option+F1 opens the Display settings, I found that Command+F1 is the closest equivalent, it switches between minitor extend and mirror. The only thing you cannot do like Win+P is the option to disconnect the external display without removing cable physically.